# Flask Deployment on Local Server

Tags: python, flask, lan

I want to deploy my flask server over my LAN. So that I can access it from other machines. I tried using `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9090)` and that kind of stuffs. Even I tried using my my IPV4 address and changing the port again and again. But nothing works.I'm unable to use it from other machines which are connected across my LAN.Can anyone help me get out of it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to open that port in your firewall.

Comment: Use Ngrok to make your local server accessible to the outside world, P.S. use this only for development purposes.

Comment: Can you please explain it some more detail ? @neilharia7

Comment: @AnimeshMondal https://ngrok.com/ use this.. make ur local server like a real server, then u can use ur localhost outside ur computer